# Radio button not selecting in laravel Dusk

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

While selecting radio button inside laravel Dusk i am getting

> Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\ElementNotInteractableException: element
> not interactable

Here is my code

```
$browser->visit('/test')
                    ->radio('question_outer_3', '29')
                     ->assertTitleContains('Test');
```

This is my templete

```
<input type="radio" class="radio user_questions " name="question_outer_3" id="option29" value="29" data-question="11" data-option="29" data-scroll-to=" #question_outer_4 ">
```

Comment: Can you show us your template?

Comment: What does the view look like?

Comment: template updated inside question?

Comment: Is element visible?

Comment: yes it is visible

Answer (score 0):

Often elements are "not interactable" when are not in the viewport (e.g. you have to scroll to reach them, or are still to be appended in the DOM after a Javascript call).

[Scrolling](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk#scrolling-an-element-into-view) and [waiting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk#waiting-for-selectors) for text may help.